# Content & footer spacing with responsiveness kept in mind

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

So, my issue occurs when I'm trying to create a footer that is 100% wide, overlapping the content width, which has it's own width.

Check out [this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5CTWhXLtTCeZkZOUVF6S0JfVEE/edit?usp=sharing) and see what I mean.

The milestone in this would be to attach the content's bottom to the green footer, and no matter the viewport, it sticks to that element, not going over it or dropping down.

It's an absolute positioned element, and for this I would also like to receive some better solution if it's possible. The website is made using Bootstrap 3, and it's going to be fully responsive. Quick responses and you'll have my thanks!

*Keep in mind that I can't really JSFiddle this. It's on our company's CMS and I would have to censor this too much to be worth of this.*

Comment: "Keep in mind that I can't really JSFiddle this. It's on our company's CMS and I would have to censor this too much to be worth of this."
But without fiddle we can't really help you :/

Comment: @Core972 you can if there is a solution you know for this. I'm sure this is being asked often, but I couldn't find anything related directly to a responsive sticky footer.

Comment: Can you please create image with desired final behavior?

Comment: I know i can help you, but i don't understand what you want to achieve? A fixed footer? Just use fixed position and width 100%

Comment: The footer can't follow the page as it scrolls, it must stick to the bottom of the content above it. 100% width is essential. @paulalexandru

Comment: So then, as i said, position fixed and width 100%. Have you tried that?

Comment: @paulalexandru Had to do some additional fixes to that, but fixed position and 100% width basically did that. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to paulalexandru for this working solution:

```
#footer {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
}
```

That did it for me, after reviewing and repositioning the HTML structure of my layout, I finally got it where I wanted it to be. Setting the **left** to be zero was necessary, otherwise it left an empty space to the left, for the footer being inside of another element which is not full width with the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize your situation (as I understand it) you have a bootstrap-based page in which each tab uses the "container" class, which can reduce the tab width depending upon your viewing screen size. What you want is a footer which will sit under the active tab, stuck to the bottom of the content, which uses the full width of the screen (meaning it is not constrained by the "container" class).  If this is what you want then try the following:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        ...
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content">
        ...
    </div>
    <footer>
        ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

Note: this will not work if the footer is absolutely positioned.

If this is not what you are looking for, please provide a little more information.